# smart pointer array deletor

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Up to now I've allocated a buffer for some data processing and deleted it afterwards. Since the code got bigger and caught exceptions at some points can occur, i thought about making it safer with a `std::unique_ptr` and came up with those solutions:

```
unique_ptr<char, void (*)(void *)> p1( (char*)operator new(bufSize), operator delete);
unique_ptr<char[], void (*)(void *) > p2( (char*)operator new(bufSize), operator delete);

memcpy(&((p1.get())[0]), "xyz", 3);
memcpy(&(p2[0]), "xyz", 3);

char x1 = p1.get()[0];
char x2 = p2[0];
```

to me the first solutions (p1) seems to be the correct one, but it's tedious to have to write (p1.get())[...]

the second solution would be the convenient one, but here is my question:

`std::unique_ptr<T[]>` seems to be templated in a special way supporting `operator[]`, which makes me wonder, if i use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` with a custom new and delete operation, is there anything that could go wrong with the ``operator[] or any other functions or is the second solution (p2) fine?

Comment: Why not just: `std::unique_ptr<char[]> p1(new char[bufsize]()); memcpy(p1.get(), "xyz", 3);`? I don't think that's incorrect, unclear, too long or confusing (unlike the posted code).

Comment: because ´new char[bufSize]´ will initialize every char, and i'm dealing with huge buffers, so that is not an option

Comment: @cppanda: `new char[bufSize]` will NOT initialize a single char. Note that `char` is not a class; it is a POD, it doesn't have constructor. However, `new char[bufSize]()` will initialize every char with `0`.

Comment: @Nawaz thanks i've probably misinterpreted some of my c docs and thought basic types will be zero initialized, but now i saw that it's just for statics and globals

Comment: If you don't want to initialize it, then don't (leave out the `()`), but then you need to deal with null-termination or keep track of the amount of bytes you wrote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`std::unique_ptr` is specialised for arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). You can just write the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> str(new char[4]);
char foo[] = "str";
std::copy(foo, foo + sizeof(foo), &str[0]);
```

If that didn’t exist you could do something similar yourself, or you could write a `using` alias and a `make_array` function which does the setting up for you and returns the correct type, then using it would be as simple as

```
auto str = make_array<char>(4);
```

… or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use raw buffers unless you absolutely need to (and there is rarely need to use raw buffers). You are probably best off using normal `new char[n]` together with `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> array(new char[n]);
```

If you absolutely need to allocate raw memory you can use `std::unique_ptr<char[], void (*)(void*)>` but the deleter function needs to match the allocation function, i.e., you need to use `operator delete[]` if you allocated the memory using `operator new[]`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unique_ptr` supports managing of dynamic arrays. You do not need to write your own deleter:

Example:

```
int main()
{
    int letter{97};
    int size{26};

    unique_ptr<char[]> arr(new char[size]());

    for (int i{}; i != size; ++i)
        arr[i] = static_cast<char>(letter++); // supports subscript

    for (int i{}; i != size; ++i)
        cout << arr[i];
}
```

While `std::shared_ptr` does not directly support managing of dynamic arrays, and you need to write your own deleter:

Example:

```
int main()
{
    int letter{97};
    int size{26};

    shared_ptr<char> arr(new char[size](), [](char *p) { delete [] p; }); // own deleter

    for (int i{}; i != size; ++i)
        *(arr.get() + i) = static_cast<char>(letter++);

    for (int i{}; i != size; ++i)
        cout << *(arr.get() + i);
}
```

Since `std::shared_ptr` doesn't have subscript operator and doesn't support pointer arithmetic, we can use `get()` to obtain a built in pointer.