# Is this correct point to free char*

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I have this code

```
{
 char *filename = createFilename(file, extension);
 ...
 ...
 delete[] filename;
}

inline char *DataSet::createFilename(LPCSTR file, LPCSTR extension)
{
  char *path = new char[strlen(file) + strlen(extension) + 1];
  strcpy(path, file);
  strcat(path, extension);

  return path;
}
```

Am I right to delete "filename" in the main function? I get ERROR_INVALID_NAME on delete. I have checked the filename and that is correct.

I know I should be using std::string but this is existing code. Please help

Comment: Don't do that. Use `std::string` and refactor original code to use more `std::string`; also, use `char` not `Char`.

Comment: How are you detecting the error? this code looks fine - unless `Char` is *not* `char`.

Comment: Where is `main` function?

Comment: By 'main' function I mean the calling function

Comment: The error looks like a file operation failure,not from your handling memory.

Comment: The delete operator never results in an ERROR_INVALID_NAME. This error is probably emitted by the code that uses the file name.

Comment: @MarkRansom Probably that's `System::Char`

Comment: Please try with `delete filename; `. Removing the index operator.

Comment: @Rndp13 No don't do that.  anything created with `new[]` needs to be deleted with `delete[]`.

Comment: Thanks @nathan for clearing my doubt.

Comment: Show the filename, I suspect that the problem is related to `delete`, how are you using the `filename`?

Comment: @Tim3880 Thanks all. It turned out to be an file name problem rather than memory

Answer (score 2):

If it's existing code and you can't change `createFilename` to return a `std::string`, then how about changing the call site to use `std::unique_ptr`. It is specialized for arrays and would be a much safer bet than doing delete on your own. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14004602/2587908).

Answer (score 1):

An error of type **ERROR_INVALID_NAME** usually occurs when the directory name, file name or volume label is incorrect. On Windows, you might have to take care of [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). For example, if the path to the file is **C:\Folder\File.ext** you should use the string **C:\\Folder\\File.ext**. In addition, some characters may not be accepted by the API you're using even though Windows allows them to be used in file and directory names. See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc956689).